# Object moving in different direction after rotating the plane, three js(v73)

Tags: three.js

I am have having issue in moving the object, when using mouse. When i move the object initially it works fine, but after rotating the scene about the y-axis, the object starts moving in opposite direction of the mouse. I have created a jsfiddle for that. Here is the code:

```
//define global variables here
var container, renderer;
var camera, scene, projector,mouseVector,controls;
var mouseX, mouseY, draggable;
var pen,c_mesh,interactiveObj = [];
var cube_selected=false;
var wallWidth=1200;
var wallHeight=400;
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once 
init();
animate();

function init(){

    container=document.createElement('div');

    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);
    //camera.position.set(0,-wallWidth/2+10,wallWidth);
    camera.position.set(0,-wallHeight/2+10,wallWidth);
  // camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,-wallWidth/2 +10,10));
    //camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10,10,10));

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);
    scene.add(ambient);

    //walls
    walls = new THREE.Object3D();

    var groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0x808080});

    var groundGeo_2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(wallWidth, wallWidth); //for roof and floor

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo_2, groundMat);
    ground.overdraw = true;
    ground.position.set(0, -wallHeight, 0);
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
    walls.add(ground);






    var cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(500,300,100);
    var c_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
     c_mesh     = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, c_material);

    c_mesh.overdraw = true;
    c_mesh.name = "first_cube";
    c_mesh.position.set(0, -wallHeight+100/2-1 ,0); //c_mesh.add(camera);
    c_mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;

    interactiveObj.push(c_mesh);
    walls.add(c_mesh);



    scene.add(walls);

    //projector = new THREE.Projector();
    mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel',onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
    //Firefox
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();

}
function render() {      
    renderer.render( scene, camera );        
}   


function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event){
    draggable = true;
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( interactiveObj, true );
    console.log(intersects);
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if(intersects[0].object == c_mesh)  {
            renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';           
            console.log("cube selected "); cube_selected=true;               
        }else{
            cube_selected=false;
        }
        draggable = false;
    }

}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event){
    draggable = false;
     cube_selected=false;
     renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
}


function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    if(draggable){
        if(mouseX != 0 && mouseY != 0){
            deltaX =  event.clientX - mouseX;
            deltaY =  event.clientY - mouseY;

            walls.rotation.y += deltaX * 0.01;
            walls.rotation.x += deltaY * 0.01;
        }
    }else if (cube_selected==true){
        if(mouseX != 0 && mouseY != 0){
            deltaX =  event.clientX - mouseX;
            deltaY =  event.clientY - mouseY;
            c_mesh.position.x  += deltaX*1.5 ;
            c_mesh.position.y  -= deltaY*1.5 ;               
        }
    }
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    render();
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
    mouseDelta = (-event.wheelDeltaY|| event.detail);
    camera.position.z += mouseDelta * 1 ;
   // console.log("camera position : "+ camera.position.z);
    render();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pn1pL4jb/5/

**What i have done:**
Added object in plane, rather then to scene because I want the same rotation of plane and object in the same direction.

Comment: Why not just use/modify the existing OrbitController? You can find it in the THREE examples

Comment: Hello Bjorke, if you go through the code , then you can see that we have not used orbit controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a 2nd answer to this problem.  The OP has added orbitControls.js to his app and now all the objects are more manageable.  Here is the whole app's .html file, updated to reflect the changes.  Now, you can click/drag to rotate the whole room.  And then you can click/drag on the chair or the sofa and drag them around the room.  Their Y positions are clamped to the ground (0.0) so that they do not incorrectly penetrate the floor.

The sliding of objects along the floor is achieved through raycasting against just the ground (when the mouse has selected them and dragging them).  The raycast returns the intersection point in world space, so I just copy that into the draggable objects' position.  Then a post-clamp of their Y positions prevent them from falling through the floor.

Even better, is the fact that we don't need localToWorld and worldToLocal matrix 'hacks' anymore because everything is relative to the Scene, which is how it is in real life. :) To prove this, I added an example update the chair's rotation around its own Y axis, so we have a spinning chair that is able to rotate around its own local center of gravity, while also being able to move its position relative to the Scene (world).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Room</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>


<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="workspace"></div>
<script>
    //define global variables here
    var container, renderer;
    var camera, scene, projector, mouseVector, controls;
    var mouseX, mouseY, draggable;
    var pen, c_mesh, interactiveObj = [], rotateObj = [], groundRaycastObj = [];
    var wallWidth = 1200;
    var wallHeight = 400;
    var chair_model, sofa_model;
    var chair_selected = false;
    var sofa_selected = false;

    var raycaster;
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
    var radius = 100, theta = 0;
    var oldIntersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    var newIntersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3(); 
    var intersectOffset   = new THREE.Vector3();

    var chair_rotate = false;
    var walls;
    var mesh_box;
    var wallright, wallleft, wallback, wallfront, ceiling, ground;
    var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.getElementById('workspace'); //document.createElement('div');

        document.body.appendChild(container);

        //camera
        //camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);
       // camera.position.set(0, -wallHeight / 2 + 10, wallWidth);
        //  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10));

        //renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x889988);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
        scene.add(ambient);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );

        camera.position.z= wallWidth;
        camera.position.y= wallWidth/2;


        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
                controls.enableDamping = true;
                controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
                //controls.enableZoom = false;



        //walls
        walls = new THREE.Object3D();


        var groundGeo_2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(wallWidth, wallWidth); //for roof and floor
        var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(wallWidth, wallHeight);

        var wallTextureRight = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/rainbow.jpg')
        });
        wallTextureRight.map.needsUpdate = true;

        var wallTextureLeft = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/rainbow.jpg')
        });

        var wallTextureFront = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall4.jpg')
        });

        var wallTextureBack = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall3.png')
        });

        var floorTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/floor.jpg')
        });
        floorTexture.map.needsUpdate = true;

        var ceilTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall4.jpg')
        });

        ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo_2, floorTexture);
        ground.overdraw = true;
        ground.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(ground);
        console.log(ground);

        wallleft = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureLeft);
        wallleft.overdraw = true;
        wallleft.position.set(-wallWidth / 2, wallHeight / 2, 0);
        wallleft.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(wallleft);

        wallright = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureRight);
        wallright.overdraw = true;
        wallright.position.set(wallWidth / 2, wallHeight / 2, 0);
        wallright.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(wallright);

        wallback = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureBack);
        wallback.overdraw = true;
        wallback.position.set(0, wallHeight / 2, -wallWidth / 2);
        walls.add(wallback);

        wallfront = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureFront);
        wallfront.overdraw = true;
        wallfront.position.set(0, wallHeight / 2, wallWidth / 2);
        wallfront.rotation.y = -Math.PI;
        walls.add(wallfront);

        ceiling = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo_2, ceilTexture);
        ceiling.position.set(0, wallHeight, 0);
        ceiling.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(ceiling);

        scene.add(walls);

        groundRaycastObj.push(walls);

        //load bed texture
        var bed_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/cb-rochelle-gray_baked.png");
        var bedMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: bed_texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        //load bed
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('js/sofa.js', function (geometry) {
            sofa_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, bedMaterial);
            for (var i = 0; i < sofa_model.children.length; i++) {
                sofa_model.children[i].material = material;
                sofa_model.children[i].userDataParent = sofa_model;
                sofa_model.children[i].name = 'sofa_model';
            }
            sofa_model.position.set(200,0, -200);
            sofa_model.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
            sofa_model.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
            sofa_model.name = 'sofa_model';
            interactiveObj.push(sofa_model);
            scene.add(sofa_model);

        });


         //load chair texture
        var chair_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/chair.png");
        var chairMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: chair_texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        //load chair
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('js/chair_model.js', function (geometry) {
            chair_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, chairMaterial);
            for (var i = 0; i < chair_model.children.length; i++) {
                chair_model.children[i].material = material;
                chair_model.children[i].userDataParent = sofa_model;
                chair_model.children[i].name = 'chair_model';
            }
            chair_model.position.set(-200,0, -200);
            chair_model.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
            chair_model.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
            chair_model.name = 'chair_model';
            interactiveObj.push(chair_model);
            scene.add(chair_model);

        });



        //IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
        //Firefox
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    }
    function animate() {


        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        chair_model.rotation.y += 0.02;
        controls.update();

        // Render the frame
        //Don't render twice, it will slow down your animation!
        //render();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }



    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        //controls.handleResize();

    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
        draggable = true;
        event.preventDefault();

    var testIntersects;
        testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
        if (testIntersects.length > 0)
            oldIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

        // find intersections
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(interactiveObj, true);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            controls.enabled=false;

            if (intersects[0].object.name == 'chair_model') {
                container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                chair_selected = true;
            } else if (intersects[0].object.name == 'sofa_model') {
                container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                sofa_selected = true;
            }
            else {
                chair_selected = false;
                sofa_selected = false;
            }
            draggable = false;
        }

    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
        draggable = false;
        chair_selected = false;
        sofa_selected = false;
        chair_rotate = false;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        controls.enabled=true;

    oldIntersectPoint.set(0,0,0);
    newIntersectPoint.set(0,0,0);
        intersectOffset.set(0,0,0);
    }


    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        var deltaX = event.clientX - mouseX;
        var deltaY = event.clientY - mouseY;

        var testIntersects;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(interactiveObj, true);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            //addRotationLine(intersects[0].object);

        } else {
            container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        }

        if (draggable) {

        } else if (chair_selected == true) {

                testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
                if (testIntersects.length > 0) {

            newIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

            intersectOffset.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                intersectOffset.sub(oldIntersectPoint);
            //uncomment below if you want more precision mouse movements of objects
            //intersectOffset.multiplyScalar(0.1);
                    oldIntersectPoint.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                        chair_model.position.add(intersectOffset); 

                }
                // clamp chair position to the ground
                chair_model.position.y = 0;

        } else if (chair_rotate == true) {
            rotate_object(chair_model, event);
        }
        else if (sofa_selected == true) {
            testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
                if (testIntersects.length > 0) {

            newIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

            intersectOffset.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                intersectOffset.sub(oldIntersectPoint);
            //uncomment below if you want more precision mouse movements of objects
            //intersectOffset.multiplyScalar(0.1);
                    oldIntersectPoint.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                        sofa_model.position.add(intersectOffset); 

                }
                // clamp sofa position to the ground
                sofa_model.position.y = 0;
        }
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
        //render(); // no need to render
    }

    function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
        // This is automatically handled for you by orbitControls.js, 
        // but you can't disable zoom on the controls - so don't type controls.enableZoom = false;

        //mouseDelta = (-event.wheelDeltaY || event.detail);
        //camera.position.z += mouseDelta * 1;
        //render(); // no need to render
    }

    function addRotationLine(objModel) {
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff,
            linewidth: 6
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(-10, 500, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(1000, 500, 0)
        );
        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        objModel.add(line);
    }
    function rotate_object(object, event) {
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var deltaX = event.clientX - mouseX;
        var deltaY = event.clientY - mouseY;

        object.rotation.y += deltaX * 0.02;
        object.rotation.y += deltaY * 0.01;
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ericlof, thanks it worked like charm. Thanks for helping me out...:)

Comment: Hi, @ericlof, there is some issue with object movement :                             

 groundIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
                if (groundIntersects.length > 0) {
                     chair_model.position.copy(groundIntersects[0].point);   
                }

Example: When the my object is touching the wall, then there is no raycaster intersection with groundplane and object, so the object is not moving.I hope you understand the issue.

Comment: Hi @anuj, glad it worked for you!  About the intersection issue, just add the walls to the groundRaycastObj list instead of the ground.  In other words - groundRaycastObj.push(walls);  The walls contain every spot you can intersect with, and the chair and sofa shouldn't be able to slide up the walls or ceiling because of the Y clamping ( chair_model.position.y = 0; ).  You could even rename the array[] to wallsRaycastObj to better describe what is being pushed onto that list.  Hope this fixes everything for you! :)

Comment: Hi @ericlof, what you suggested we tried that before,but there is some issue with this solution.
When we add walls in raycasting object and pick the object from upper left corner, then the object rapidly statrts moving in the walls direction because that time it picks the point from the side walls, while my object is in the middle of the room(this case happens when the room is exactly in front of user, not tilted).

Comment: I was just looking at the interactive cubes example and the way that three.js does it is they have an offset from when you first click, your first intersection point, up until your current mouse position intersection point.  Then the objects' positions are moved by adding just this offset to their current positions.  When I get a few moments, I'll try it out and report back.  Or if you want to try it, let me know if you can get it working.  Talk to you soon!

Comment: Yay, success!  I added the offset idea from the three.js interactive cubes example and it works great now.  I re-pasted my new html code into the above answer.  Just select it all, copy and paste into your project and try it out.  It should work how you've been wanting now.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that when you rotated the walls/ground with the mouse drag, the cube's rotation was not updated to match.  So when you went to drag the cube after a world rotation, the cube is still operating in its old coordinate system.  Also, be careful how you add children to parents.  The cube should be a child of the scene (or world coordinate system) if you intend to move it all around.  If it is a child of the floor or walls, things can get wacky really fast.  :)

I updated your JSFiddle as well as cleaned up the code a little bit:
https://jsfiddle.net/aucyekux/

The magic is happening on line 126 with the copying of the wall's rotation into the cube's rotation so it matches:

```
c_mesh.rotation.copy(walls.rotation);
```

I won't assume how much 3D math you know, but I'll just say that copying the ground's rotation essentially creates a new frame of reference or local coordinate system for the cube so that when you drag it to the right, and the code says x = x + ... , its new coordinate system has its x direction pointing in the same direction as the ground/walls' new x direction (after the rotation you performed on them).

Hope this makes sense - don't worry if you don't quite get how it all works.  I am a veteran 3D game programmer hobbyist for 20 years and I still sometimes forget how this all works and I have struggled with it plenty.  I also refresh my understanding by browsing [scratchapixel](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry) (the 3D math / coordinate system primer section) every now and then.  It keeps all this 3D math stuff fresh.  Good luck to you! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Erichlof, it worked like charm. You saved my day.Thanks again buddy.

Comment: @anuj rajput, Hi, no problem - glad to be of help!  I would also add, like bjorke said earlier, if all you want to do is move the camera around the scene and pick and drag stuff, like a 3d model editor, then Three.js's orbit controls will make your camera movement and object interactions much easier.  In other words, the scene objects remain still and the camera flies around them in a circle pattern, always looking at the center of the scene.  But if you have to be able to move the camera around through the world, FPS-style, then what you're doing will work.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Hii @erichlof , 
As mentioned by you on git ..please  post your reply / discussion  here rather than Git hub.

Comment: Hi again @anuj rajput , I think I have it figured out now.  Here's the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxnzao76/

Comment: ... - Now when you rotate the floor, everything rotates together.  Then, you can individually select the cube and move it according to the camera's orientation.  X+ is right, Y+ is up, and so on.. Finally, when you again rotate the floor, the cube rotates along with it, in addition to its new position offset.  So if it is located in the corner of the floor, it stays over that corner throughout the rotation drag, and its own center rotates around the scene in sync with the floor. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Hi again @erichlof, thanks for your answer, its working perfectly in x and y plane, but i don't need y movement, so when i change it to z its not working.
I tried to update line 134 by c_mesh.position.z -= deltaY * 1.5; as i want to move the mesh within the plane,but it not moving perfectly.

What i want exactly it to move the mesh within the plane.

Comment: Ok I understand now what you're wanting.  At the moment, I'm away from my desktop and typing this message on mobile.  I'll try it out late tonight - I think I have the solution but jsfiddle doesn't like touch events from my phone and I need to try it out to make sure - will be back soon!

Comment: Hi, here's the JSFiddle 2.0, haha : https://jsfiddle.net/oxnzao76/  Now the cube stays sitting on the ground at all times.  You can rotate the whole scene and the cube stays in its correct position.  Finally, when you click and drag on the cube, it slides along the ground in the X-Z plane and does not change its Y position.  MouseX controls sliding cube left and right while MouseY controls cube sliding toward you and away from you (all in relation to where the camera is pointing).  How is this now?  If you would like an explanation of the new ".localToWorld" stuff, let me know :)

Comment: Sorry, disregard that fiddle link - stackoverflow wouldn't let me edit after I realized I linked to the wrong fiddle - frustrating.  Anyway here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/v4x6mqtt/  Hope this works how you want now! :)

Comment: Hi, your code works correctly, thanks for your precious time and hard work. Actually i have 2 objects, in my code, and one object is working perfectly with your code, but another object is not working correctly.Sofa object is working perfectly but chair object is not working.So, what i am doing is, i am sharing my demo url with you,:
http://istation-demo.cladev.com/room.html

it would be great if you have a look, the function in which we have implemented your code in **function onDocumentMouseMove(), line:276**

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay, I didn't realize you had responded 2 days ago.  Anyway, thanks for the link - that helps me understand what you want.  The short answer is every object in 3D platforms (like Three.js) has its own transform matrix.  Even the big Scene object has its own matrix.  Whenever you call position or rotate on an object, it looks up the chain of its parents and first uses their transform matrix as a reference.  So the walls and floor look up to the Scene object's matrix as reference.  Since you added the sofa and chair to the walls, they look up to the walls (continued)..

Comment: which in turn looks up to the Scene (its parent).  Every child bases its transform on its parent.  So when you load the chair and sofa, you should not add a position and rotation change on them right away, because that is offsetting their frame of reference in relation to their walls parent.  Their position and rotation should be 0,0,0;  Try commenting out the following lines 146 and 147: chair_model.position.set(-200, -wallHeight + 100 / 2 - 1, 0); chair_model.rotation.set(0, 80, 0);  Do the same for the sofa model.

Comment: Now both should work when you click and drag them because they don't have any offsets on their local frame of reference.  The only parent they look up to is the walls, which may or may not be rotated by the user, but that's ok.  My seemingly tricky localToWorld and worldToLocal lines that magically made the dragging work, utilizes a change in the chair and sofa objects' frame of reference. localToWorld temporarily short-circuits their connection to the walls parent (which is all messed up due to user's rotation, but that's fine) and instead makes them look up to the Scene (world) object (cont)

Comment: for its transform matrix (which for the world, is usually 0,0,0 all the time).  Then when you drag them, they are moving through the world as frame of reference, without any consideration for the walls rotation (the connection to them has been severed).  worldToLocal connects back to whatever default transform they had, and since they are children of the walls, they default back to the walls as a frame of reference for rotations.  I noticed you wanted to rotate the chair around its own axis maybe later, just make sure you use these short-circuits, otherwise the chair will fly around the world

Comment: , orbiting the whole scene incorrectly, when you just wanted it to rotate around its own center of gravity (like a spinning chair).  If you have problems with that in the future, just post the new code back here and I will take a look.  I'm going to stop using up all these comments blocks now (ha ha).  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @ericlof, thanks a lot for your help, when i comment the line 146 and 147, everything is working fine but initially the objects stick up to the roof. I have 4 or 5, object if i don't set their initial position it will not look good as all of them will be at same position. Sorry for bothering you much, but you have always been a saver for me...:)

Comment: Hi, instead of commenting out lines 146 and 147, replace them with the following: chair_model.localToWorld(chair_model.position);
                        chair_model.position.set(-200, -wallHeight + 100 / 2 - 1, 0);
                        chair_model.scale.set(0.30, 0.30, 0.30);
                        chair_model.worldToLocal(chair_model.position);   Do the same for the couch.  This will position them correctly when the scene loads...

Comment: Again, when you make changes to the chair and sofa, such as position and scale, it has to be in relation to the world (scene) matrix and not a local offset that will be incorrectly added to the walls matrix when you later add the chair and sofa to the walls as children.  Unfortunately, I cannot get the rotation (0,80,0) of the chair to work, which is why I left it out in the suggested code block above.  I spent a while with it, and no matter how I tried, when the chair is rotated, it offsets the mouse dragging by 80 degrees, which is wrong...

Comment: From what I've seen of your app so far, I think you are reaching the maximum 'hacks' that you can get away with.  If you add 4 or 5 objects to that room, your matrix-handling code is going to start to look like spaghetti.  It will soon become unmanageable I'm afraid.  If I were developing this room demo, I would scratch all the stuff about adding children to other objects.  Instead I would add all world objects, walls, floor, chair, sofa to the scene (or world).  Then just throw a copy of orbit controls.js into the script loaders and you will have perfect camera animation with zooming...

Comment: , and all the objects will be relative to the world (which is the way it is in real life).  I know this would be a slight step back for you, but trust me - it will make your three.js coding life MUCH easier if all the objects are relative to the scene.  You can then add local rotations easily to all the objects without any headaches.  When you're at that point and ready to add local rotations, ping me your closed GitHub three.js old issue and I will help.  You will need the worldToLocal and localToWorld again, even with orbitControls, but it will work, I promise! Best of luck to you :)

Comment: I found the perfect example for you: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes    It works exactly how your app should work in the future.  You can rotate the whole scene, and then click and drag on the objects and move them wherever.  It does use trackballControls however, but just replace that with orbitControls if you like - both are very similar.  This should help get you started on the right path.  Let me know if you need help when it's time to add local rotations and spinning chairs and stuff :)

Comment: Hi @ericlof, I have added orbitControls and added objects to the scene, rather then wall. But, still the same issue. Please find the updated code:
http://istation-demo.cladev.com/room.html.

Comment: Thank you the link, and for adding orbitControls - I will take a look and get back to you soon! :-)

Comment: Yay, success!  I will post the solution along with the whole updated .html file in a new answer to this topic...

Comment: Hi @ericlof, i am facing the issue in collision detection, in the same example which we are working on, we want that our object should not move out of the room. I have created another question for the, any help of yours would be highly appreciated. Here is the link of the new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843564/prevent-objects-from-moving-outside-room-in-three-js

Answer (score 0):

Change line 143 of the fiddle to:

```
    c_mesh.position.x  += deltaX*1.5 * Math.cos( walls.rotation.y);
```

When you rotate the scene, the plane the mouse moves on doesn't rotate with it.  So you have to act like it does by scaling by the cosine of the rotation.

Comment: Hi, @fluffybunny.If works fine when we use this but when we rotate our plane to 180 degree but if we rotate it to 90 or 270 degree we again face the same issue.

Comment: Yes, my solution is just for the x axis. you fix the y axis by use Math.Sin.

Comment: hi, lets talk first about x axis... now rotate plane in x -axis by 90 and your solution stop working ... should i first get what is my current plane rotation and after that try to change position .