# Prevent objects from moving outside room in three js

Tags: three.js

I have created a room in three js and added various objects in it. But,
the objects are moving out of the room. Here is the url on which my code is running:

http://istation-demo.cladev.com/room.html

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I haven't been back to this website in a while and I only now saw your earlier post from March 8. Would you mind re-linking to your project (it currently is not being served and the link doesn't show) and I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: Hi @ericlof, here is the updated link:
http://istation-demo.cladev.com/room-final.html.
Our main issue is collision of objects, we don't want our objects to pass through other object, thanks

Comment: Hi @anuj rajput I'll be happy to help, but first, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946735/object-moving-in-different-direction-after-rotating-the-plane-three-jsv73/34997947?noredirect=1#comment59384683_34997947   and tried to add my changes to your old picking/moving code?  I ask because your current example has the old incorrect picking/moving behavior which might make collision detection debugging unnecessarily harder.

Comment: Hi Anuj, I have to create a wall and add windows on it, which can be dragged by the user until they decide where to put it on the wall, and click on Ok button. I was thinking of creating another mesh for the window, which will be over the wall mesh, and can be dragged over it. When the user clicks ok, I will redraw the whole wall mesh with the window in it. I think I will have to implement this collision thing also. Please suggest some examples or direction or approach I can start looking into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prevent objects leaving the room or colliding with each other, you must have at least a simple form of collision detection.  Most 3D engines, three.js included, have Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes ( or AABB ) for all the 3d objects that are created.  In three.js to get access to bounding boxes, the easiest way is to call 
`var boundingBoxHelperObject = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( object )`
  If you add it to the scene, it shows up as a wireframe grey box that fits tightly around the object.  If you call update on the helper (as you will see shortly), it will update to the dimensions and movement of the 3d object in real time - pretty cool!

Then, to perform collision detection on all these boxes, you call
`boundingBoxHelperObject.box.intersectsBox( anotherBoxHelperObject.box )`

which outputs true if colliding or false if not colliding.  Then perform the appropriate actions, such as moving the box back a frame to prevent it from escaping a room or penetrating another solid object, or changing both colliding objects' colors, or whatever you want.

Here's the final code sample with my corrected picking/dragging code from the last post you made months ago, plus the new bounding boxes and collision testing code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Room</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>


<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div id="workspace"></div>
<script>
    //define global variables here
    var container, renderer;
    var camera, scene, projector, mouseVector, controls;
    var mouseX, mouseY, draggable;
    var pen, c_mesh, interactiveObj = [], rotateObj = [], groundRaycastObj = [];
    var wallWidth = 1200;
    var wallHeight = 400;
    var chair_model, sofa_model;
    var chair_selected = false;
    var sofa_selected = false;

    var raycaster;
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
    var radius = 100, theta = 0;
    var oldIntersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    var newIntersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3(); 
    var intersectOffset   = new THREE.Vector3();
    var chairOldPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    var sofaOldPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

    var chair_rotate = false;
    var walls;
    var mesh_box;
    var wallright, wallleft, wallback, wallfront, ceiling, ground;
    var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";
    var chairBox, sofaBox;
    var wallrightBox, wallleftBox, wallbackBox, wallfrontBox;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.getElementById('workspace'); //document.createElement('div');

        document.body.appendChild(container);

        //camera
        //camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);
       // camera.position.set(0, -wallHeight / 2 + 10, wallWidth);
        //  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10));

        //renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x889988);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
        scene.add(ambient);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );

        camera.position.z= wallWidth;
        camera.position.y= wallWidth/2;


        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
                controls.enableDamping = true;
                controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
                //controls.enableZoom = false;



        //walls
        walls = new THREE.Object3D();


        var groundGeo_2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(wallWidth, wallWidth); //for roof and floor
        var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(wallWidth, wallHeight);

        var wallTextureRight = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/rainbow.jpg')
        });
        wallTextureRight.map.needsUpdate = true;

        var wallTextureLeft = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/rainbow.jpg')
        });

        var wallTextureFront = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall4.jpg')
        });

        var wallTextureBack = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall3.png')
        });

        var floorTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/floor.jpg')
        });
        floorTexture.map.needsUpdate = true;

        var ceilTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/walls/wall4.jpg')
        });

        ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo_2, floorTexture);
        ground.overdraw = true;
        ground.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(ground);
        console.log(ground);

        wallleft = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureLeft);
        wallleft.overdraw = true;
        wallleft.position.set(-wallWidth / 2, wallHeight / 2, 0);
        wallleft.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(wallleft);

        wallleftBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( wallleft );
        wallleftBox.update(wallleft);
            //wallleftBox.box.min.x -= 0.1;
        //wallleftBox.box.max.x += 0.1;
        //scene.add(wallleftBox);

        wallright = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureRight);
        wallright.overdraw = true;
        wallright.position.set(wallWidth / 2, wallHeight / 2, 0);
        wallright.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(wallright);

        wallrightBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( wallright );
        wallrightBox.update(wallright);
            //wallrightBox.box.min.x -= 0.1;
        //wallrightBox.box.max.x += 0.1;
        //scene.add(wallrightBox);

        wallback = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureBack);
        wallback.overdraw = true;
        wallback.position.set(0, wallHeight / 2, -wallWidth / 2);
        walls.add(wallback);

        wallbackBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( wallback );
        wallbackBox.update(wallback);
        //scene.add(wallbackBox);

        wallfront = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, wallTextureFront);
        wallfront.overdraw = true;
        wallfront.position.set(0, wallHeight / 2, wallWidth / 2);
        wallfront.rotation.y = -Math.PI;
        walls.add(wallfront);

        wallfrontBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( wallfront );
        wallfrontBox.update(wallfront);
        //scene.add(wallfrontBox);



        ceiling = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo_2, ceilTexture);
        ceiling.position.set(0, wallHeight, 0);
        ceiling.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        walls.add(ceiling);

        scene.add(walls);

        groundRaycastObj.push(walls);

        //load bed texture
        var bed_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/cb-rochelle-gray_baked.png");
        var bedMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: bed_texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        //load bed
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('js/sofa.js', function (geometry) {
            sofa_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, bedMaterial);
            for (var i = 0; i < sofa_model.children.length; i++) {
                sofa_model.children[i].material = material;
                sofa_model.children[i].userDataParent = sofa_model;
                sofa_model.children[i].name = 'sofa_model';
            }
            sofa_model.position.set(200,0, -200);
            sofa_model.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
            sofa_model.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
            sofa_model.name = 'sofa_model';
            interactiveObj.push(sofa_model);
            scene.add(sofa_model);

        sofaBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( sofa_model );

            // comment next line out if you don't want to see the wireframe sofa boxHelper
            scene.add(sofaBox);

        });


         //load chair texture
        var chair_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/chair.png");
        var chairMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: chair_texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });

        //load chair
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('js/chair_model.js', function (geometry) {
            chair_model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, chairMaterial);
            for (var i = 0; i < chair_model.children.length; i++) {
                chair_model.children[i].material = material;
                chair_model.children[i].userDataParent = sofa_model;
                chair_model.children[i].name = 'chair_model';
            }
            chair_model.position.set(-300,0, -200);
            chair_model.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
            chair_model.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
            chair_model.name = 'chair_model';
            interactiveObj.push(chair_model);
            scene.add(chair_model);

        chairBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( chair_model );

        // comment next line out if you don't want to see the wireframe chair boxHelper
            scene.add(chairBox);

        });



        //IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
        //Firefox
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    }
    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        chair_model.rotation.y += 0.02;

    chairBox.update(chair_model);
    sofaBox.update(sofa_model);
    //wallrightBox.update(wallright);
    //wallleftBox.update(wallleft);
    //wallfrontBox.update(wallfront);
    //wallbackBox.update(wallback);



        controls.update();

        // Render the frame
        //Don't render twice, it will slow down your animation!
        //render();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }



    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        //controls.handleResize();

    }

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
        draggable = true;
        event.preventDefault();

    var testIntersects;
        testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
        if (testIntersects.length > 0)
            oldIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

        // find intersections
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(interactiveObj, true);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            controls.enabled=false;

            if (intersects[0].object.name == 'chair_model') {
                container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                chair_selected = true;
            //oldIntersectPoint.copy(chair_model.position);
        chairBox.material.color.set('white');
            } else if (intersects[0].object.name == 'sofa_model') {
                container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                sofa_selected = true;
            //oldIntersectPoint.copy(sofa_model.position);
        sofaBox.material.color.set('white');
            }
            else {
                chair_selected = false;
                sofa_selected = false;
            }
            draggable = false;
        }

    }

    function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
        draggable = false;
        chair_selected = false;
        sofa_selected = false;
        chair_rotate = false;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        controls.enabled=true;

    oldIntersectPoint.set(0,0,0);
    newIntersectPoint.set(0,0,0);
        intersectOffset.set(0,0,0);

    chairBox.material.color.set('grey');
    sofaBox.material.color.set('grey');
    }


    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        var deltaX = event.clientX - mouseX;
        var deltaY = event.clientY - mouseY;

        var testIntersects;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(interactiveObj, true);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            //addRotationLine(intersects[0].object);

        } else {
            container.style.cursor = 'auto';
        }

        if (draggable) {

        } else if (chair_selected == true) {

                testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
                if (testIntersects.length > 0) {

            var okToMove = true;

            chairOldPosition.copy(chair_model.position);

            newIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

            intersectOffset.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                intersectOffset.sub(oldIntersectPoint);
            //uncomment below if you want more precision mouse movements of objects
            //intersectOffset.multiplyScalar(0.1);
            // store old intersect point for next frame
            oldIntersectPoint.copy(newIntersectPoint);

                        chair_model.position.add(intersectOffset);
            chair_model.updateMatrixWorld(true);
            //chairBox.updateMatrixWorld(true);
            chairBox.update(chair_model);

            // default
            chairBox.material.color.set('white');   

            if( chairBox.box.intersectsBox(sofaBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                chairBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( chairBox.box.intersectsBox(wallrightBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                chairBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( chairBox.box.intersectsBox(wallleftBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                chairBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( chairBox.box.intersectsBox(wallfrontBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                chairBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( chairBox.box.intersectsBox(wallbackBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                chairBox.material.color.set('red');
            }

            // if NOT ok to move and chair is hitting something,
            if ( !okToMove ) {
                // put chair back where it was
                chair_model.position.copy(chairOldPosition);
            }


                }
                // clamp chair position to the ground
                chair_model.position.y = 0;

        } else if (chair_rotate == true) {
            rotate_object(chair_model, event);
        }
        else if (sofa_selected == true) {
            testIntersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(groundRaycastObj, true);
                if (testIntersects.length > 0) {

            var okToMove = true;

            sofaOldPosition.copy(sofa_model.position);

            newIntersectPoint.copy(testIntersects[0].point);

            intersectOffset.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                intersectOffset.sub(oldIntersectPoint);
            //uncomment below if you want more precision mouse movements of objects
            //intersectOffset.multiplyScalar(0.1);
                    oldIntersectPoint.copy(newIntersectPoint);
                        sofa_model.position.add(intersectOffset);

            sofa_model.updateMatrixWorld(true);
            //sofaBox.updateMatrixWorld(true);
            sofaBox.update(sofa_model);

            // default
            sofaBox.material.color.set('white');    

            if( sofaBox.box.intersectsBox(chairBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                sofaBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( sofaBox.box.intersectsBox(wallrightBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                sofaBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( sofaBox.box.intersectsBox(wallleftBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                sofaBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( sofaBox.box.intersectsBox(wallfrontBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                sofaBox.material.color.set('red');
            }
            else if( sofaBox.box.intersectsBox(wallbackBox.box) ) {
                okToMove = false;
                sofaBox.material.color.set('red');
            }

            // if NOT ok to move and sofa is hitting something,
            if ( !okToMove ) {
                // put sofa back where it was
                sofa_model.position.copy(sofaOldPosition);
            }

                }
                // clamp sofa position to the ground
                sofa_model.position.y = 0;
        }
        mouseX = event.clientX;
        mouseY = event.clientY;
        //render(); // no need to render
    }

    function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
        // This is automatically handled for you by orbitControls.js, 
        // but you can't disable zoom on the controls - so don't type controls.enableZoom = false;

        //mouseDelta = (-event.wheelDeltaY || event.detail);
        //camera.position.z += mouseDelta * 1;
        //render(); // no need to render
    }

    function addRotationLine(objModel) {
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff,
            linewidth: 6
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(-10, 500, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(1000, 500, 0)
        );
        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        objModel.add(line);
    }
    function rotate_object(object, event) {
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        var deltaX = event.clientX - mouseX;
        var deltaY = event.clientY - mouseY;

        object.rotation.y += deltaX * 0.02;
        object.rotation.y += deltaY * 0.01;
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you! :)